# including a file in base64 into XML in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, base64

I am looking for a way to include a PDF file into an XML file. I have the PDF on the harddisk and want to print out an XML file containing the PDF in base64 encoding. I could find ways to do this in the net but not with Perl. I guess there will be a oneliner for doing this.

The expected output is something like this:

```
<file id="918" filesize="143356" extension="pdf">
    <embed encoding="base64">JVBERi0.....
....
</embed>
  </file>
```

Comment: You could try [MIME::Base64](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Base64) combined with [XML::Writer](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Writer)

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I want to import journal papers into a repository and this is what they want as a format.

Comment: @K J, base64 is designed for use where binary data is not supported. XML is such a place. It is a standard practice to use base64 to include binary data in XML.

Comment: @Stefan Müller, What problem are you having? Reading a file? Encoding a string using base64? Generating XML?

Comment: The first comment solved my problem. Thanks! The MIME::Base64 module has everything I was looking for. The documentation says how to process a file and print the encoding.